# Populating a map that has been instanced

Tags: java, maps, bluej

Im trying to populate a map that has been declared as an instance variable but nothing happens when i execute the code.

Here is my class (very basic/early)

```
public class RacingDrivers
{
private Map<String, String> racingNumbers;

/**
* Constructor for objects of class RacingDrivers
*/
public RacingDrivers()
{
   racingNumbers = new HashMap<String, String>();
}

/**
* A method to populate the racingNumbers map.
* 
* 
*/
public void populateMap()
{
  racingNumbers.put("44", "Lewis Hamilton");
  etc etc

}
```

Then i execute this code:

```
RacingClub RC = new RacingClub();
RC.populateMap();
```

RC is created but the map is not populated?

Comment: According to the presented code, the map *is* populated.

Comment: try the debugger-mode `Ctrl+D`

Comment: Yes, it should be fine as @MarkoTopolnik says. Maybe if you show the code you use to access/retrieve/check the contents in the map it would be easier to determine what is going wrong.

Comment: Did you try any output? You could simply use `System.out.println(racingNumbers);` to display the `HashMap`.

Comment: How you notice that value is not put in the map, code seem good

Comment: Executing System.out.println(runningMembers); creates Error: line 1 - cannot find symbol - variable runningMembers
@ambigram_maker

Comment: What is `RacingClub`?  It doesn't appear in your code *except* in your last two lines.  Did you mean to instantiate a `RacingDrivers` object, not a `RacingClub`?

Comment: I never wrote `racingMembers! I wrote `racingNumbers`, i.e. the name of ur `HashMap`!

Comment: @Paul Good observation. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're creating an instance of class `RacingClub`.

The `racingNumbers` `Map` is an instance field of class `RacingDrivers`.

The `Map` is initialized in the constructor of the `RacingDrivers` class.

Answer (score 1):

you initialize the class  **RacingDrivers**

and then call

```
RacingDrivers  rc = new RacingDrivers();

rc.populateMap();
```